# Composer dependency with attached sorce control repository

Tags: version-control, composer-php

I have an app that uses some of our own libraries as dependencies. Let's say `vendor/me/somelib` is such a dependency. When working on the main app, often times I am also changing the `somelib` dependency. I am using Mercurial for VCS of `somelib`.

Is there a way that when composer initializes the dependency, it initializes it as a VCS (Mercurial) repo so that when changing `somelib` I can then easily push changes to the main `somelib` repo? Or is there some other way to achieve the same need (to easily propagate changes in a dependency back to its main repo).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309120/1058964

Comment: I don't know if I understand it: so does it mean, in my project's composer.json, I would add a local path to a local repository for the library?